# C++ Armadillo code in C#

Tags: c#, c++, armadillo

I would like to use [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) in a C# application, Anyone had any experience using armadillo in C#, I am not familiar with C#.

I know armadillo has a .dll, is there anyway to import this dll in c#...

Comment: You may be interested in this question: [C# linear algebra library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392857/c-linear-algebra-library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to use LAPACK, BLAS or Eispack with C# you can use [DotNumerics](http://www.dotnumerics.com/)

DotNumerics is a Numerical Library for .NET. The library is written **in pure C#** and has more than 100,000 lines of code with the most advanced algorithms for Linear Algebra, Differential Equations and Optimization problems. The Linear Algebra library includes CSLapack, CSBlas and CSEispack, these libraries are the translation from Fortran to C# of **LAPACK, BLAS and EISPACK**, respectively.

Comment: Armadillo is much faster than DotNumerics, you can use them together like this https://github.com/mrbm2007/DotNumerics

Answer (score 5):

Armadillo is heavily based on templates, so you won't be able to use it with C# without overwhelming work.