# C# Algebra Linear Library

Tags: c#, linear-algebra, least-squares

I'm looking for a C# linear algebra library.

I wan't to solve a homogeneous linear system with least squares minimization.

I've been trying to use some librarys but I was just able to find the trivial solution.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Have other questions on this topic not helped (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392857/c-sharp-linear-algebra-library)? Which libraries have you tried? Math.NET? Please give details. :)

Comment: Perhaps Singular Value Decomposition of the [Accord.NET](http://accord-net.origo.ethz.ch/wiki/features) would help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See:

- http://www.meta-numerics.net/
- http://www.mathdotnet.com/
- http://linearalgebra.codeplex.com/

They are open source too!

Answer (score 3):

As commenter oleksii mentioned, you can use [Accord.NET](http://accord.googlecode.com) to achieve this as well. But you can also use its [Solver extension method](http://accord.googlecode.com/svn/docs/html/M_Accord_Math_Matrix_Solve_1.htm) for that instead of manually creating a SVD:

```
// Suppose you have matrices A and b and would
// like to find x such that Ax = b (solve for x). 

// So you would have matrices
double[,] A = ... // matrix A
double[]  b = ... // vector b

// Then all that is necessary is to call:
double[] x = A.Solve(b, leastSquares: true);
```

And that is it. It also works when `b` is a matrix as well.

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of this library.

Comment: Are you sure this works? I used your code. Unfortunately, there is an error: "Error 1 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Solve' and no extension method 'Solve' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
" Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Hmmm... Please make sure you are adding the directive "using Accord.Math;" on top of your source file, and see if it helps. If it doesn't, please let me know!

Comment: Like the disclaimer! :D