# Library for Eigenvector and Eigenvalue computation in C Sharp

Tags: emgucv, eigenvector, eigenvalue

I am working with Face Recognition. I need to compute Eigenvector and Eigenvalue from a matrix. I am using C sharp . Is there any library for Eigenvector and Eigenvalue computation. I think Emgu CV has no function for Eigenvector and Eigenvalue computaion. I am new so I don't know well . I need a library for Eigenvector and Eigenvalue computaion for C Sharp. Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# linear algebra library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/392857/c-sharp-linear-algebra-library)

Answer (score 2):

Emgu is good but if you want full control and a pure c# library I strongly suggest to use [Accord.Net Framework](http://code.google.com/p/accord/), it's a full framework for research projects done in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the namespace MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra of the Math.NET (MIT/X11 license) library.

The documentation is here:
http://nmath.sourceforge.net/doc/numerics/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.html

You find it here:
https://github.com/mathnet

You'll be interested in the class EigenvalueDecomposition
http://nmath.sourceforge.net/doc/numerics/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.EigenvalueDecomposition.html